# Pandas - How can I get only the last element of a list to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that has lists in some of the columns:

```
email                         A                      B
something@gmail.com    [name1, name2]    [thing1, thing2, thing3]
another@gmail.com          [name]           [thing1, thing2]
```

I only want to have the last element of each list in each row, like this:

```
email                    A         B
something@gmail.com    name2    thing3
another@gmail.com      name     thing2
```

Is there an easy way of doing it? I initially though of something in the likes of
`data['newcolumn'] = data['A'][Number of row][-1]`, but I'm a little bit lost on hoiw doing the "number of row" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you could do something like the following

```py
def return_last_element(row):
    # If the row of the given column is list or a tuple, get the last element
    if isinstance(row, (list, tuple)):
        return row[-1]

    # Otherwise just return the value
    else:
        return row

# Loop over all columns, and apply the function to each row of each column
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(return_last_element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to this, create a simple function called getLastValue() it takes your list in each row and returns the last value of that list. see below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'email' : ['something@gmail.com ', 'another@gmail.com'],
    'A': [['name1','name2'], ['name']],
    'B': [['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'], ['thing1', 'thing2']]
}

def getLastValue(aList):
    return aList[-1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(getLastValue)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(getLastValue)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Series.str[-1]`:

```
In [145]: df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['something@gmail.com', 'another@gmail.com'], 'A':[['name1', 'name2'], ['name']], 'B':[['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'], ['thing1', 'thing2']]})

In [146]: df
Out[146]: 
                 email               A                         B
0  something@gmail.com  [name1, name2]  [thing1, thing2, thing3]
1    another@gmail.com          [name]          [thing1, thing2]

In [148]: df['A'] = df['A'].str[-1]

In [149]: df['B'] = df['B'].str[-1]

In [150]: df
Out[150]: 
                 email      A       B
0  something@gmail.com  name2  thing3
1    another@gmail.com   name  thing2
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you:

```
data['newA']=[data['A'][i][-1] for i in range(len(data))]
data['newB']=[data['B'][i][-1] for i in range(len(data))]
```